# how to disable one or more option in dropdown menu in navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a navigation bar with 5 elements, drop down menu field, textarea and another text field. what i need:
- to disable all navigation bar elements except Home. then when i blur the text field remove attr disabled from them and activate again.
- to separate all the values in the dropdown menu field started with 001 in additional drop down menu under the master in the navigation bar without the third part in the line (url) , append values started with 002 in additional drop down menu under CSS without (url) and 003 under javascript also without (url) .
- when user click in logout option under home window close.
Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/ov43ebko/1/

here are the jQuery I have implemented:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.css,.jscript,.jquery').attr('disabled','disabled');
  $('.logOut').click(function(){ 
  window.close();
});

// to split lines based on semicolon.
function check(){
 var lines = $('.hiddenText textarea').val().split(/\n/);
 var texts = [];
 for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
 }
 for (var i=0; i < texts.length; i++) {
  var removed1 = texts[i].split(';');

  $(".masters").append($("<ul><li>").text(removed1[0]));
  $(".css").append($("<ul><li>").text(removed1[1]));
  $(".jscript").append($("<ul><li>").text(removed1[2]));
 }
}

 // to split dropdown menu choices to lines.

function c1() {
 var resultLines = $('.filledField').find('option').size();
 var textArea ="";

 for (var i = 1; i <= resultLines; i++) {

 var xItem = $('.filledField').find('option:nth-child(' + (i) + ')').text(); 
 textArea +=  xItem ;

 //code to split xItem into individual variables
}
$('.hiddenText textarea').val('');
$('.hiddenText textarea').val(textArea);
check();
}
$(".field").blur(function(){
$('.css,.jscript,.jquery').prop("disabled", false);
c1();
 });
```

});

Comment: `$('.css,.jscript,.jquery').prop("disabled", "");`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Not working

Comment: try `removeAttr('disabled')`

Comment: The first code to disabled these classes not working

Comment: try more variants like `.attr('disabled','')`